# If $X_1, X_2$ are independent continuous random variables what is the joint density of $(X_1, X_1+ X_2)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence, density-function

I asked myself the following question.

Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ have densities $f$ and $g$.
What is the joint density of $(X_1, X_1+X_2)$?

My effort:
Based on the heuristics from [Joint distribution of $(X_1,X_1 + X_2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420897/joint-distribution-of-x-1-x-1-x-2)
that covered a discrete case.

I kind of want to do something like the following:

$
\mathbb{P}(X_1 = x_1, X_1+X_2 = x_2) = \mathbb{P}( X_1+X_2 = x_2 \mid X_1 = x_1)  \mathbb{P}(X_1 = x_1) =  \mathbb{P}(X_2 = x_2-x_1)  \mathbb{P}(X_1 = x_1)  = f(x_1) g(x_2-x_1). 
$

But of course all these numbers are 0 and when I try with $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq x_1)$ the details do not seem to work out.

Comment: Continuous random variables do have non-zero values for their *probability **density** functions*.

Comment: Sure, but I can't just replace the $\mathbb{P}$ by the corresponding densities.

Comment: Probability density functions are *derived* from probabilities.  Derivatives have definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint density of $(X_1, X_2)$ is $f_{(X_1, X_2)}(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$

It holds that
$$
(X_1, X_1+X_2) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} X_1  \\ X_2  \end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Notice that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has determinant 1.

Therefore from the transformation theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Vector_to_vector
it follows that the joint density of $(X_1, X_1+X_2)$ is given by
$$
f_{(X_1, X_1+X_2)}(x,y) =  f_{(X_1, X_2)}(x, y-x) = f(x)g(y-x). 
$$